# How can I split a single dataframe column, containing multiple values, into a transposed table of 'flags'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to separate a single column in a dataframe, that contains multiple comma separated values, into a transposed table that contains columns which flag every potential comma separated value.

e.g.

```
name         purchased             total_value
-----------------------------------------------
John         Eggs, bread, milk     100
Steve        Milk, cheese, wine    140
Susan        Beer, cheese, milk    120
```

Needs to become:

```
name    total_value   eggs   bread   milk   cheese   wine   beer
-----------------------------------------------------------------
John    100           1      1       1      0        0      0
Steve   140           0      0       1      1        1      0
Susan   120           0      0       1      1        0      1
```

As a small added complication, the purchased column as spaces after the commas, and some of the values have capitals.

Can anyone help me get from A to B?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert all values to lowercase by [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html), call [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original.

For remove original `purchased` is possible use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) or [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df['purchased'] = df['purchased'].str.lower()
df = df.join(df.pop('purchased').str.get_dummies(', '))
```

```
df = df.drop('purchased', 1).join(df['purchased'].str.lower().str.get_dummies(', '))
```

---

```
print (df)
    name  total_value  beer  bread  cheese  eggs  milk  wine
0   John          100     0      1       0     1     1     0
1  Steve          140     0      0       1     0     1     1
2  Susan          120     1      0       1     0     1     0
```